# Prove the correctness of the RSA for $GCD(m_i,n)=1$ and $GCD(m_i,n) \neq1$

Tags: encryption, rsa

How to make a proof of the correctness of the RSA encryption and decryption formula for $GCD(m_i,n)=1$  and $GCD(m_i,n) \neq1$ where encryption is defined as $c_i = m_{i}^e$ mod n and decryption $m_i = c_{i}^d$ mod n.

So thanks @poncho for giving tips, I wrote a following proof:

Recall that the integers $e > 0$ and $k > 0$ are chosen such that
$ ed = 1 + k(p − 1)(q − 1)$

It suffices to show that the two congruences

$(m^e)^d \equiv m\ \textrm{mod}\ p  $ and $(m^e)^d \equiv m\ \textrm{mod}\ q  $ hold. p and q are distinct primes, so $gcd(p,q) = 1$ and the above congruences imply that

$(m^e)^d \equiv m\ \textrm{mod}\ n  $ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. If $m \equiv 0\ \textrm{mod}\ p  $, then certainly
$(m^e)^d \equiv m\ \textrm{mod}\ p  $. If $m \not\equiv 0\ \textrm{mod}\ p  $, then $m^{p-1} \equiv 1\ \textrm{mod}\ p  $ beacuse of Fermat's little theorem ($a^{p-1} \equiv 1\ \textrm{mod}\ p $) hence,

$$ (m^e)^d \equiv m^{1 + k(p - 1)(q - 1)} \equiv m(m^{p-1})^{k(q-1)} \equiv m 1^{k(q-1)} \equiv m\ \textrm{mod}\ p
   $$

Therefore $(m^e)^d \equiv m\ \textrm{mod}\ p  $ holds for all integers m. Replacing p by q in the previous argument shows that $m \equiv (m^e)^d \textrm{mod}\ q  $ holds for all integers m

Any comments about correctness of my proof are appreciated!

Comment: For the people who answer or upvote HW problems; This is our consensus [Do we want to update the way we handle homework questions?](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1117/18298) in short **Only hints and in comments.**. If you don't agree on this, go on and downvote there. Or ask a new question for the policy change!

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously a homework problem, and so I'll only give a hint:

- Can you prove it modulo $p$ (where $p$ is one of the prime factors of $n$)?  That is, can you prove that $(m^e \bmod p)^d \bmod p \equiv m \pmod p$, for any $m$?
- Would the same proof also approve modulo $q$?
- Given the above two, how can you show that it applies modulo $p \cdot q = n$?

Comment: Thanks, @poncho! I rewrote the question with my version of proof. Hope it is correct now